# Алгоритм подсчёта минимума в окне на изображении

Tags: алгоритм, обработка-изображений, фильтрация, асимптотика

Задача очень простая.

Дано изображение, массив, пускай int'ов, размером m на n . Мы хотим пройтись по нему окном k на l, и в каждом окне рассчитать минимум (затем этот минимум куда-то записать, но это уже к алгоритму не относится).

Алгоритм в лоб даст сложность O(mnkl).

Можно применить алгоритм с min-кучей (heap), тогда асимптотика понизится до O(log(kl)n(mk+l)) (может я ошибся, но у меня получилось так).

Алгоритм с кучей выглядит так: с шагом вправо или влево добавляем в кучу вновь  пришедшие числа (k или l добавлений, по log(kl) на каждое), и столько же удаляем (столбец или строку, время будет такое же, как и для добавления).

Для поддержки удаления кучу нужно реализовать хитро, через прокси-объект, который будет держать в себе, помимо самого числа, индекс его местоположения в куче, куча будет обновлять эти индексы, и через них выполнять запрос на удаление (на самом деле это стандартный трюк, если мы будем реализовать скользящую k-статистику через кучи, я не знаю алгоритма, не использующего прокси).

Для случая одномерного массива скользящий минимум можно также подсчитать за линейное время с помощью очереди. Для двумерного случая мне это решение обобщить не удалось.

Насколько верно направление, в котором я думаю. Может есть какой-то очевидный алгоритм, который я упустил, и сижу, изобретаю сложности на пустом месте. Насколько адекватен алгоритм с кучей? Не получится ли так, что из-за накладных расходов на прокси мы просядем настолько по времени, что наивная реализация окажется шустрее?

Ну и может есть способ быстрее, чем алгоритм с кучей? По аналогии с одномерным случаем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы правы, алгоритм для двумерного случая можно получить из [одномерного с деком](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190184/can-min-max-of-moving-window-achieve-in-on/12195098#12195098) (deque).

Для начала проходим по каждой строке, получая двумерный массив скользящих минимумов для *горизонтальных* окон заданной ширины.

Затем проходим по каждому столбцу полученного массива, получая двумерный массив минимумов для *вертикальных* окон заданной высоты

Вот пример шагов для получения результата для ячейки (1,1) с окном 4х3 [отсюда](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53810)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А [тут](https://www.nayuki.io/page/sliding-window-minimum-maximum-algorithm) есть [код на Java](https://www.nayuki.io/res/sliding-window-minimum-maximum-algorithm/MinMaxImageFilter.java) (часть Min/max image filter) для квадратного окна (метод `filterByBoxPattern`)

Comment: Ответ очень полезный, но не даёт полного ответа на вопрос) Прочитав статьи по вашим ссылкам я понял, как правильно сделать быстрый алгоритм. Но он в ответе не содержится, так что я пока не знаю, отмечать ли ответ как правильный) Но полезность его неоспорима. Наверное, позже отредактирую, добавив алгоритм, и помечу как верный.

Comment: Хм.. А чего тут не хватает? Про одномерный случай, я так понял, Вы знаете.

Comment: Согласен, объяснение с учётом ссылок (и знания об одномерном случае) вполне достаточное.